как реализовать чат с админом django-channels
Всем привет!
Хочу реализовть 'обратную связь' в виде чата. Подключил django-channels, но возникла проблема разграничения достпупа - если отправлять личное сообщение админам, то оно дублируется у пользователя так как используется цикл отправки сообщения- ничего более умного я не придумал
 def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    print(text_data_json)

    if not self.user.is_authenticated:
        return
    target_msg = message

    # send private message to the target
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        **f'inbox_{помогите}',**
        {
            'type': 'private_message',
            'user': self.user.username,
            'message': target_msg,
        }
    )
    # send private message delivered to the user

    self.send(json.dumps({
        'type': 'private_message_delivered',
        'user': self.user.username,
        'target': **{помогите}**
        'message': target_msg,
    }))

Жирным выделил то, куда нужно вставить логику разграничения.

вместо '{поиогите}' должны быть админы, но так , что бы пользователю не транслировалась отправка сообщений по количеству админов,а только одно
Навсякий случай скину JS
chatSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data)
    switch (data.type) {
        case "private_message":
            let now = new Date();
            myDiv.appendChild(myDivMess = document.createElement('div'))
            myDivMess.className += 'message'
            myDivMess.appendChild(myName = document.createElement('div'))
            myName.textContent += data.user + '\n';
            myDivMess.appendChild(myMessage = document.createElement('div'))
            myMessage.textContent += data.message
            myDivMess.appendChild(myDate = document.createElement('div'))
            myDate.className += 'date'
            myDate.textContent += data.time

            myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight
            chatMessageInput.focus();
            break;

        case "user_join":
            myDiv.appendChild(myDivMess = document.createElement('div'))
            myDivMess.className = 'joinedTheRoom'
            myDivMess.textContent += data.user + " joined the room.\n";
            myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight
            break;
        case "user_leave":
            myDiv.appendChild(myDivMess = document.createElement('div'))
            myDivMess.className = 'joinedTheRoom'
            myDivMess.textContent += data.user + " left the room.\n";

            break;
        // case "private_message":
        //     chatLog.textContent += "private_message from " + data.user + ": " + data.message + "\n";
        //     break;
        case "private_message_delivered":

            myDiv.appendChild(myDivMess = document.createElement('div'))
            myDivMess.className += 'message'
            myDivMess.appendChild( myName = document.createElement('div'))
            myName.textContent +=  data.user + '\n';
            myDivMess.appendChild( myMessage = document.createElement('div'))
            myMessage.textContent += "private_message to" + data.message
            myDivMess.appendChild( myDate = document.createElement('div'))
            myDate.className += 'date'
            myDate.textContent += data.time
            myDiv.appendChild(myDivMess = document.createElement('div'))
            break;

